# C++ manipulators?

Tags: c++

How does the c++ standard define the recognition of manipulators or just manipulators in general?

For example:

```
using namespace std;
ostream& hello_manip(ostream& os){
  os<<"Hello there, fine fellow!"; return os;
}
int main(){
  cout<<hello_manip;
}
```

The code **cout << hello_manip** would seem to be translated into **operator<<( cout,  hello_manip )** or **cout.operator<<(hello_manip)**, but instead it takes up the form of **hello_manip( cout )**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an overload of `operator<<` that accepts a function pointer and invokes it.  No magic involved.

Processing of simple manipulators such as yours is described in section 27.7.3.6.3 of the Standard.

> `basic_ostream<charT,traits>&  operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&  (*pf) basic_ostream<charT,traits>&))`
>
> 1. Effects: None. Does not behave as a formatted output function (as described in 27.7.3.6.1).
> 2. Returns: `pf(*this)`.
>
> `basic_ostream<charT,traits>&  operator<<(basic_ios<charT,traits>&  (*pf) basic_ios<charT,traits>&))`
>
> 1. Effects: Calls `pf(*this)`. This inserter does not behave as a formatted output function (as described in 27.7.3.6.1).
> 2. Returns: `*this`.
>
> `basic_ostream<charT,traits>&  operator<<(ios_base&  (*pf)(ios_base&))`
>
> 1. Effects: Calls `pf(*this)`. This inserter does not behave as a formatted output function (as described in 27.7.3.6.1).
> 2. Returns: `*this`.

More complex manipulators (which accept parameters and carry state) are implemented by returning functor objects, which have their own `operator<<` overloads.

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that. Now this makes total sense. Not even sure if I should leave this question here - it might seem misleading.

Comment: @Eximius, you should definitely keep it in case someone else comes along and finds it. They'll probably have the same eureka as you.